# Make fields sortable in CP

Tags: plugin-development, field, hook

I'm displaying list of fields on frontend (using `craft.fields.getFieldsByGroupId`) and for that purpose I need the fields in group to be in particular order.

Is there a way to add 'order' property to fields model and make them sortable in CP? I can't find appropriate hook (if it exists)